# Preventing writable modifications to Oracle database, using Python.

Tags: python, database, readonly, cx-oracle

Currently using cx_Oracle module in Python to connect to my Oracle database. I would like to only allow the user of the program to do read only executions, like Select, and NOT INSERT/DELETE queries.

Is there something I can do to the connection/cursor variables once I establish the connection to prevent writable queries?

I am using the Python Language.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: You should restrict the user in the database server.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to issue the statement "set transaction read only" as in the following code:

```
import cx_Oracle

conn = cx_Oracle.connect("cx_Oracle/welcome")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("set transaction read only")
cursor.execute("insert into c values (1, 'test')")
```

That will result in the following error:

ORA-01456: may not perform insert/delete/update operation inside a READ ONLY transaction

Of course you'll have to make sure that you create a Connection class that calls this statement when it is first created and after each and every commit() and rollback() call. And it can still be circumvented by calling a PL/SQL block that performs a commit or rollback.

The only other possibility that I can think of right now is to create a restricted user or role which simply doesn't have the ability to insert, update, delete, etc. and make sure the application uses that user or role. This one at least is fool proof, but a lot more effort up front!